# ASP.NET Web API : is it possible to manipulate multiple kinds of resources in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Our system is designed with frontend website and backend ASP.NET Web API. Here is the business scenario: there is one table called `WorkSession`, it records the detail of one work session, like when it start, when it ends... When one work session ends, we need to calculate the corresponding points earned by that worker, and insert one row into the `Accounting` table.

While the worker ends one work session on the front website, it sends request to the backend API via Javascript. Now I want to update the `WorkSession` table, and at the same time, insert one row into the `Accounting` table.

Previously, my understanding is that one controller should be designed for only one kind of resource. But if I design an `AccountingController`, is it redundant because front website will send two http requests to the web server?

In the code shown here, I want to manipulate the two tables in one PUT method of one controller. Is this going against the REST principles?

```
public class WorkSessionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ClockOut([FromBody] WorkSessionViewModel workSessionViewModel) 
    {
       // Update the row in WorkSession table
       // Insert one row in Accounting table
    }
}
```

Comment: what is important? your biz logical or a coding rule? If I am the coder who works on client, I may say how silly if I have to request two times.

Comment: I mean the REST rule, handle two kinds of resources in one Controller.

Answer (score 0):

What about logical dependency in these two updates?
does it matter if one request fails and another succeeds?
If your answer is yes, you have to implement these two commands in one transactional command.

SRP is not a true or false principle, so you have two separate logic until separation helps you to have a more maintainable and easy-to-read code base.

Comment: Thanks @Javad letting me know that SRP is not a true or false principle. Do you think it is suitable to name the Controller as WokrSessionController even it manipulates two resources?

Comment: Hi @Javad, It turns out that they have logical dependency. So, where do you suggest I need to put the transaction, in service layer or controller layer?

Comment: In my opinion, it should be recognized by the business side. how business knew this behavior. A common example of this type of separation is aggregate system logs, we never separate that to another controller, and it's completely ok.

For the transactional issue, I think the controller is not a good point to handle transactions. So service is a better choice.